# My cobeblocks doesn't compile my C++ code. I cannot make much sense from the build messages. How do I solve this?

Tags: codeblocks, ubuntu-14.04

My cobeblocks doesn't compile my C++ code. I cannot make much sense from the build messages. All i know is that linker files are missing.How do I solve this?

the errors in the build messages window  are;
cannot find -lgdi32
cannot find -luser32
cannot find -lkernel32
cannot find -lcomctl32

Comment: Are you on 64 bit Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes i am on 64 bit ubuntu